# Typescript generic type for nested object properties

Tags: reactjs, typescript, type-inference

I want to achieve something like this so that the type of the `Component` can be inferred and so the `props` can be automatically safely typed.

```js
type ComponentsType<T extends React.FC<any>> {
  [key: string]: {
    Component: T;
    props?: React.ComponentProps<T>
  };
}

const components: ComponentsType = {
   RedButton: {
      Component: Button,
      props: { // <- this should be automatically typed to take props of Button
        color: 'red'
      }
   },
   BlueButton: {
      Component: Button,
      props: { // <- this should be automatically typed to take props of Button
         color: 'blue'
      }
   },
   FullWidthCard: {
      Component: Card,
      props: { // <- this should be automatically typed to take props of Card
         variant: 'full-width'
      }
   },
}
```

But the above typing won't work because the generic part is on the root of the object AKA `components`, not on each property AKA `RedButton` or `FullWidthCard`.

So is there a way for typescript for run through them one by one and infer the Component one by one?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve expected behavior, you need to infer each component and props from function arguments. I mean, you need to create an extra function.

```js
import React, { FC, ComponentProps } from 'react'


const Button: FC<{ color: string }> = (props) => null
const Card: FC<{ variant: string }> = (props) => null


type WithProps<T> =
    T extends Record<infer Key, infer _> ? {
        [P in Key]: T[Key] extends { Component: infer Comp, props: infer PassedProps }
        ? Comp extends React.JSXElementConstructor<infer Prps>
        ? { Component: Comp, props: ComponentProps<Comp> & Record<Exclude<keyof PassedProps, keyof Prps>, never> }
        : never
        : never
    } : never


const components = <
    Comp extends React.JSXElementConstructor<any>,
    Item extends { Component: Comp },
    Components extends Record<string, Item>>(dictionary: Components & WithProps<Components>) => {}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBiAwtoROBAHZIUwAKUEYAznAL5wBmDIcA5FKgy8AUKLSUm8AEIBXGDEoAuAoQA8ecQBtoyyVGAUA5mwB8cALxwAFGAbMAlBbMUZmzcPEVJcQiigATZSJ1OAA3P2AUGl0YfSNTC2tbRiZHc2dXd1EYAE8wJDgAdWAYAAt6FNUAFTNzYTgGuCq4JAAPGGp-FmRxANUDDiQoOABpJBzsAaG4AH0zAH5cesaVgG1aOANR8YBdZSrVsZydlvbOljxScipozYpB4auwbGTmZSnh2hQmJiR-CuYbGWKwaiyepw6FC6iEEMAAdAApADKAA0AKKaJAgagwUheWIyDDQfr3ab0ZgmYEgxaXMiQG4wZRPF52JhMumUHEApiqJ5mABkMN6-lUaNaaE0Mn8SFUAGtxhAOHAvj8-tzsPKcorlVAKdgqKEhmZWFSVsoDUNTY1zUhDVAqewbXbRB4JPBxNccSxLKoqeC2pDoch0PDkejMdiaHi9ISFFBVFEciZMFSAJIdHgB864Hwchns8BsFMrJ6cmgsLNQ7pIYWqPQGQzYdNYkwmKz%20YAYYCUPw5Av0r1wQXFMrc3l5r0mNJmHCiE2uz3lqyzlbIfyyeRKJYgxql-NwDcKCjFndwV5s7enlZaHR8AT%20ERXk0rVgnhpSSVIQ9blenvc45Rv2PK0GnPZRfyvBobygZReAAI0-R9T2fRpXypfBMmKfwyl8AJwJA3NF0ZHw-H8N8QTAy9ILCCIomI3gOEyABaAB3YBsNKJCdxQho0NYewgA)

**`Comp`** - infered component

**`Item`** - infered dictionary item, `component&props` object

**`Components`** - infered whole argument.

**`WithProps`** - iterates through each object of passed argument and checks whether `props` obhect is assignable to component props. If yes - return props, otherwise negate all invalid props to `never`.

```js
components({
    RedButton: {
        Component: Button,
        props: {
            color: 'red'
        }
    },
    BlueButton: {
        Component: Button,
        props: {
            extra_prop:42, // DRAWBACK, no error
            color: 'blue'
        }
    },
    FullWidthCard: {
        Component: Card,
        props: {
            variant_invalid_prop: 'full-width' // expected error
        }
    },
})
```

But there is a drawback, this function will accept extra props, like `extra_prop`.

P.S. I hope somebody will come up with better solution where extra props will be invalid also